# Use local IDE such as Microsoft visual code to use additional compute

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, data-science, databricks

I am trying to figure out the best way about how we can use local IDE such as microsoft visual studio code to use distributed computing power. Currently, we are brining data locally but it doesn't seem like sustainable solution because of reasons like in future scale of data will grow, cloud data security, etc. One workaround we thought of is to tunnel into EC2 instances but would like to hear what's best way to solve this in machine learning/data science environment (we are using databricks and AWS services).

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. An IDE is only for writing and debugging code, you cannot "use" it for distributed computing. That has to happen completely in your runtime environment

Comment: @UnholySheep: In a sentence, how I can write code locally, let's say using jupyter notebook while using AWS compute power. My local machine can't handle data load beyond a limit.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview You can actually run remote development if you have a remote machine with more computing power.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are connecting IDE to ccomputer . I have used VS Code for running scripts against HDInsight cluster . Before I fire by scripts I do configure the clusters against which it is going to run . The same is true on the Databricks also.